# Are asynchronous servlets possible in Java 1.5?

Tags: java, ajax, servlets, asynchronous, java-5

I have a servlet that does a lot of file IO to a network share and therefore runs long. I want to implement a progress bar on the front end instead of a simple spinner gif so the user knows something is actually happening and it's not just "stuck."

I'm running Java 1.5 on Websphere 6.1 and there's no upgrading in sight. I know with the Servlet 3.0 spec, asynchronous servlet support is built-in, but I'm wondering if there is a workaround or something similar where I can fake it to look asynchronous?

I make a simple ajax call using jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/servlet.action",
    success: function(json, status, xhr) {
        alert("success");
    }
});
```

Can the servlet periodically send status updates back to the client as it makes its way through the process, or should the client make periodic status requests to the servlet (or another servlet that has access to the main servlet's status)?

I cannot upgrade the versions of Java and/or Websphere at this time.

Comment: I think your problem is the websphere version. See [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/cwlp_websockets.html) "Version 8.5.5.3 and later of the WebSphere web server plug-in support full duplex communication"

Comment: You'd probably be better off using a WebSocket for this

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this:

1. Send an asynchronous request to start the process. This servlet updates a static object with the status of the processing. (like a Map of some kind of session/request identifier → process status)
2. Periodically send another asynchronous request to a different servlet with access to that static object and return the current status. The status could be a number (% complete), a String (status message), or an Object that contains a bunch of information.
3. Then the periodic request can handle the status and update a progress bar or something.

This can be done in any type of servlet container with any Java version.